# ubuntu 17.04 Switching to DNS server issue

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns

I have been using Ubuntu 17.04 for a few months and have not had any issues. Once i arrived in Florida and started using Spectrum Communications cable provider. Sporadically while on WIFI I started receiving these log lines in /var/log/syslog. It leads to the WIFI connection becoming totally unusable. I have done some research and started using Googles DNS but it seems the problem is not with which DNS server you use. I have also tried turning off DNSSEC but that does not seem to remedy the problem either. I am curious to see if it is a configuration issue or should i call my provider to troubleshoot with them. The other machines in the house work fine but they are not using ubuntu 17.04.

```
Jun 09 10:51:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Grace period over, resuming full feature set
(UDP+EDNS0+DO+LARGE) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
Jun 09 10:51:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:37 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:37 systemd-resolved[1013]: Grace period over, resuming full feature set
(UDP+EDNS0+DO+LARGE) for DNS server 75.114.81.1.
Jun 09 10:51:39 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:42 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:43 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:43 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:43 systemd-resolved[1013]: Using degraded feature set (UDP+EDNS0+DO) for DNS server
75.114.81.1.
Jun 09 10:51:44 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:44 systemd-resolved[1013]: Using degraded feature set (UDP+EDNS0+DO) for DNS server
75.114.81.2.
Jun 09 10:51:48 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:48 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:48 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:50 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:53 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:53 systemd-resolved[1013]: Using degraded feature set (UDP+EDNS0+DO) for DNS server
8.8.8.8.
Jun 09 10:51:53 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:53 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:55 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:58 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:58 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:51:58 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:03 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:03 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:04 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:04 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:09 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:09 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:13 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:13 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:14 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:14 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:17 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:17 systemd-resolved[1013]: Grace period over, resuming full feature set
(UDP+EDNS0+DO+LARGE) for DNS server 8.8.4.4.
Jun 09 10:52:17 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:18 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:18 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:20 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:20 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:22 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:22 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:23 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:23 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:24 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:24 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:25 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:25 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:27 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:27 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:29 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:29 systemd-resolved[1013]: Using degraded feature set (UDP+EDNS0+DO) for DNS server
8.8.4.4.
Jun 09 10:52:29 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:29 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:29 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:32 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:32 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:38 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:38 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:39 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:39 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:39 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:40 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:40 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:40 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:43 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:43 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:45 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:45 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:45 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:45 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:45 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:45 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:47 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:47 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:48 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:48 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:50 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:50 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:50 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:50 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:52 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:52 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:54 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:54 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:54 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:54 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:55 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:55 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:56 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:56 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:57 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:57 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:59 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:52:59 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:00 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:00 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:01 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:01 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:03 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:03 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:04 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:04 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:05 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:05 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:05 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:05 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:08 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:08 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:10 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:10 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:10 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:10 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:10 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:10 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:13 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:13 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:15 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:15 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:15 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:15 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:15 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:15 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:19 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:19 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:20 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:20 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:20 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:20 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:24 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:24 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:25 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:25 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:26 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:26 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:26 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:26 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:28 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:28 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:29 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:29 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:30 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:30 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:31 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:31 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:35 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:35 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:39 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:39 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:39 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:39 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:40 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:40 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:40 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:40 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:44 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:44 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:44 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:44 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:44 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:44 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:45 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:45 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:45 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:45 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:49 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:49 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:49 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:49 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:49 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:49 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:50 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:50 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:54 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:54 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:55 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:55 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:55 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:55 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:56 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:56 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:59 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:59 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:59 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:53:59 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:00 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:00 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:00 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:00 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:01 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:01 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:04 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:04 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:04 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:04 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:05 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:05 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:09 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:09 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:09 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:09 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:10 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:10 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:10 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:10 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:14 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:14 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:14 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:14 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:14 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:14 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:15 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:15 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:15 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:15 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:19 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:19 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:20 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:20 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:20 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:20 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:21 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:21 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:24 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:24 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:25 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:25 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:26 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:26 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:30 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:30 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:30 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:30 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:31 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:31 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:34 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:35 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:35 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:39 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:39 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:40 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:40 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:44 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:44 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:46 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:46 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:49 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:49 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:51 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:51 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:55 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:55 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:56 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:54:56 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:55:01 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.2 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:55:01 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.8.8 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:55:04 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 8.8.4.4 for interface wlp3s0.
Jun 09 10:55:04 systemd-resolved[1013]: Switching to DNS server 75.114.81.1 for interface wlp3s0.
```

Comment: i solved my issue by following instructions from this link's top answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/454427/network-issues-since-trusty

Answer (score 2):

There may be a couple different issues here, a DNS/DNSSEC [systemd-resolved] and NetworkManager issue.  Some people report disabling DNSSEC in systemd-resolved worked, others switched to 'unbound' for their stub resolver.  Switching to unbound alone for me did not resolve the issue.

http://www.hecticgeek.com/2017/04/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-dns-issues/

However, adding this fix for NetworkManager (and still running with unbound) seems to have done so.  In fact, network speed just went through the roof.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1681513

https://askubuntu.com/questions/905997/serious-wi-fi-network-issue-on-ubuntu-17-04

edit the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file

And disable `scan-rand-mac-address` in the `[device]` section:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

I've not been running long with the above two fixes in place, but long enough I was hitting this problem before the changes.

P.S.  I recently moved to Florida and Spectrum also, so I went through a lot of red herring research trying to blame them for this as well....

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this, been several frustrating weeks of trying all the other DNS related solutions, I made this modification about 40m ago and I already see an enormous improvement and no error logs (connections used to start flooding with the "Switching DNS..." after 5-10 minutes, became unusable after 30-60m).